# Trigonometry: sin(x) getting negative value

Tags: python

I am trying to solve a homework: I am required to write a program which will calculate the length of a ladder based on two inputs, that is the desired height to be reached and the angle created by leaning the ladder toward the wall.

I used the following formula to convert degrees to radians :

```
radians = (math.pi / 180) * x # x is the given angle by the user.
```

I imported the math library as well to use its functions.

```
def main():

    import math 

    print("this program calculates the length of a ladder after you give the height and the angle")

    h = eval(input("enter the height you want to reach using the ladder"))
    x = eval(input("enter the angle which will be created be leaning the ladder to the wall"))

    radians = ( math.pi / 180 ) * x

    length = h / math.sin(x)

    print("the length is:", length)


main()
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?
I know the code is missing something and would appreciate it if someone could help me fill the gap.

Comment: Don't use `eval`. You know you want a `float` value, so use that: `h = float(input("..."))`.

Comment: BTW: to convert between angles use `math.radians(x)` and `math.degrees(y)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for grabbing my attention to the float point.
BTW, is it o.k to paste a homework question and ask for help to solve it ? Or will it be deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never used `radians` after you calculate it.

i.e. `length = h / math.sin(radians)`

Answer (score 0):

To make crickt_007's right answer absolutely clear: `radians` which you did not use after you calculate it should be the argument of the sine:

```
length = h / math.sin(radians)
```

Answer (score 0):

you calculate `radians`,thats ok,but problem is you never used that `radians`  value. i think your code must be changed as follows :)

```
def main():

    import math 

    print("this program calculates the length of a ladder after you give the height and the angle")

    h = eval(input("enter the height you want to reach using the ladder"))
    x = eval(input("enter the angle which will be created be leaning the ladder to the wall"))

    radians = ( math.pi / 180 ) * x

    length = h / math.sin(radians)

    print("the length is:", length)


main()
```

if your both input will be 5,output is `the length is: 57.36856622834928`